# How to do Flex date deduction and addition

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

In flex, I am trying to do date deduction and addition, but couldn't find a way to do it.

e.g.: 
public var dateNow:Date=new Date();

How can I get the Date 3 months earlier than dateNow?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the Date constructor for this.  The first argument to Date's constructor takes either a year or a timestamp.  You can use the `Date.time` property to get the timestamp from a date object.  Once you have the timestamp you can add/subtract some number of seconds from it, and then pass it to `new Date(timestamp)` and you get a brand new date which represents the new timestamp.

Edit;
As a commenter pointed out, time manipulation may not be the best way to go.  But you can still use the Date constructor as follows:

```
var now:Date = new Date();
var threeMonthsAgo = new Date(now.fullYear, 
                              now.month - 3,  
                              now.date, 
                              now.hour, 
                              now.minute, 
                              now.second, 
                              now.millisecond);
```

The Date constructor is smart enough to deal with negative values, or values greater than 11.

Comment: Date math is much more complicated than converting to seconds and adding/subtracting.  You have to take time of day, days per month, leap years, time zones, and sometimes different contexts into account.

Comment: Yes, but in case of the month it's not that difficult.

Comment: Even in case of the month it can be difficult :) 

When 2 – 1 = 2 when doing math operations with dates in ActionScript
http://www.jabbypanda.com/blog/2011/09/when-2-1-when-doing-math-operations-with-dates-in-actionscript

Answer (score 3):

Try the DateUtils open source library.

I use it extensively in the Flextras Calendar and it works great. I'm pretty sure there is a DateAdd method.  To get a date 3 months earlier, you can just add a negative 3.

http://flexdateutils.riaforge.org/

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is built-in Date arithmetic. Even the [official adobe documentation for the Date class](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/201/langref/Date.html#getTime%28%29) creates date math from scratch when using it.

Take a look at the above link. The documentation creates a DateMath class with static methods to do the sort of thing you want. Given that, I'm not sure why they didn't make is a part of the standard, but that's the way it is. I'd suggest copying it from there and expanding on it.

Answer (score 0):

another alternative is Peter's Dates for lazy people, I love it coming from CF
http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/24/date-math-for-lazy-people/

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var dObj:Date = new Date();

DateField_Now.formatString = DateField_LastWeek.formatString = "YYYY-MM-DD";

DateField_Now.selectedDate = dObj;

dObj["date"] += 7;
DateField_LastWeek.selectedDate = dObj;
```